# Need some help with MongoID and many-to-many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, mongoid

Using mongoid 2.0.0.beta.20, if it means.

The goal is quite easy, but I can't get it. I have a `User` model, which

```
references_many :worlds, :inverse_of => :users
```

and a `World`, which, of course,

```
references_many :users, :inverse_of => :worlds
```

In human words, user can visit 0..inf worlds, and a world can be visited by 1..inf users. World should store a list of ids of users who been there, and user should store a list of worlds' ids he visited. Looks pretty easy, but doesn't want to work for me.

Now, there is an instance of User (let's call him `someone`) and two instances of World (`earth` and `mars` maybe). When I try to say that `someone` visited `earth`, there is no problem:

```
earth.users << someone
earth.users.count # => 1
```

Then, I want to say that `someone` also been on `mars`:

```
mars.users << someone
mars.users.count # => 1
```

Everything's OK? Not sure:

```
earth.users.count # => 0
someone.worlds.count # => 0
```

I also tried to use `:stored_as => :array` parameter for relations, but there was no success at all (direction doesn't matter):

```
someone.worlds << earth
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.<<
```

(and any other `Array` methods raises that I trying to deal with nil)

Maybe I missed something in the docs or doing something wrong. Please, help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgrade to the latest rc, then you can use the new macro for doing those kinds of relations:

`references_and_referenced_in_many :worlds`

In beta 20, you were on the right track using :stored_as => :array. Trying setting a default like so and it should work for you.

`references_many :worlds, :stored_as => :array, :default => []`

Answer (score 0):

With MongoID I believe you may have to explicitly `earth.save` the document after modifying it with something like `earth.users << someone` in order to persist changes to the 'document'.

Comment: I explicitly call `save` in my controller (controller works with only one instance, so there is no other way)